# How can I disable Viber icon from tray

Tags: 15.04, icons, system-tray, viber

I need to disable Viber indicator from tray. How can I do it?

Comment: have you checked in the settings for viber? many times there is an option to enable or disable the system tray icon from the app itself.

Comment: Yes, I have. There is no option for disable tray icon.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling `viberwrapper-indicator`?